# C# Where to cache big data tables

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, oracle, asp.net-web-api

I have to execute a long running PL/SQL query and need to store the result set somewhere and serve to UI request. After some time need to refresh it automatically / manually. 
there will be multiple result sets need to be handled in the same way. Each and every result set will have millions of records.
My project is using AngularJS with Web API.
I am using ADO.net with Oracle Client, not entity framework.

What I feel, .net MemoryCache is not suitable because the no.of resultset and size will be keep on growing.

I am planning to cache it in MongoDb. is there any other solution you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: What about [Redis](http://redis.io/) ?

Comment: Why not just serve up the query to the UI request?

Comment: Are you literally planning to serve millions of records to the UI requests? Probably not, in which case you might consider using Oracle materialized views, which are designed specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says **"Each and every result set will have millions of records"**

In that context,
Caching in server is not a good idea. Even distributed caching may result in performance issue.

- Create dedicated physical tables in oracle to store your results
- Load & refresh the result table whenever required
- Fetch and return the result from results table

If you can't insert/delete records from your oracle database you may need to go with a dedicated application database.

Even if you return millions or records from web API, the angular application should process all your data. That might result in long running JavaScript and client side performance.

Comment: Actually, not required to return full result set to UI. result set will be filtered for UI request.

Answer (score 1):

Redis is a good solution. Check out http://redis.io/

Comment: why the downvote? He asked for another solution to mongoDb